# 3D Plot Grid-Lines

Tags: plotting, image3d, grid-lines

I have a simple 3D plotting question, but having difficulty finding the option which might have changed from a previous version as I have recently updated to Mathematica 13.1. When using the Plot3D function, how do you produce the inner grid-lines as shown in the attached image on the right? Thanks for any assistance. [image: 3D plot with and without grid-lines]
[image: 3DPlot Function]

Comment: The code shown in your screen shot does not produce a plot of anything.  Please post working or at least copyable code so we can all help you.  I think you have to at least provide a definition of your function, `var[x,y,n]`

Comment: Use the option [`FaceGrids`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FaceGrids.html)

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks good sir but FaceGrids has a different effect, like caging your 3DPlot. POW 3D plots not desired.

Comment: You don't have to use `FaceGrids -> All`, you can specify which faces have gridlines.

Comment: @BobHanlon Did not know that, many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Plot3D[x*y, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

Comment: I knew it was something simple I forgot!

Answer (score 6):

Using [`FaceGrids`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FaceGrids.html)

```
Plot3D[x*y, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 FaceGrids -> {
   {{0, 0, -1}, {{-6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6}, {-6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 
      6}}},
   {{0, 1, 
     0}, {{-6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6}, {-30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30}}},
   {{-1, 0, 
     0}, {{-6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6}, {-30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30}}}}]
```

[image]